# How to access auto-bound functions from React class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'll explain my problem with an example code.

```
var func = function(e){alert(this.props.val)};
var inner = <button onClick={func}>Click me</button>;

var Comp = React.createClass({
    func,
    render: function(){
        return inner;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Comp val="testing"/>,document.getElementById("container"));
```

The problem here is, since I am declaring the component outside React.createClass(), the onClick that is passed to the button is not the auto-bound function of the class, so I won't have access to the `this` of the component, hence I can't access props.

Anyway around this?
Remember I have to declare the component outside.

Here is the link to the issue I raised on the github page of react. [Link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7052)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [stateless function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions):

```
var func = function(e){alert(this.props.val)};
var Inner = (props) => <button onClick={props.func}>Click me</button>;

var Comp = React.createClass({
    func,
    render: function(){
        return <Inner func={this.func}/>;
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing solution!! How did you think of this?? Thanks!